# epoll_wait returned Bad file descriptor

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming, epoll

I'm writing a multi-thread server in C++. The main event loop is like the follows:

```
for (;loop_enabled_;)
{
    int ret = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, epoll_event_buf_size(), -1);
    if (ret >= 0)
        handle_events(events, events + ret);
    else
    {
        std::error_code ec(errno, std::system_category());
        logger->critical("Error in epoll_wait: {}", ec.message());
        throw std::system_error(ec);
    }
}
```

However, in rare cases the `epoll_wait` may fail with [Bad file descriptor](https://travis-ci.org/htfy96/c10k-server/jobs/196497191#L698) even it has successfully finished several iterations.

According to `man epoll_wait`:

> ERRORS
>
> ```
> EBADF  epfd is not a valid file descriptor.
>
> EFAULT The memory area pointed to by events is not accessible with write permissions.
>
> EINTR  The call was interrupted by a signal handler before either (1) any of the requested events occurred or (2) the timeout expired; see signal(7).
>
> EINVAL epfd is not an epoll file descriptor, or maxevents is less than or equal to zero.
> ```

`EBADF` suggested that `epollfd` was invalid in my code, but since it has finished several iterations, what does `invalid` mean here? Will `close` before `epoll_ctl(EPOLL_CTL_DEL)` cause this?

Comment: Your code does not perform epoll_ctl(EPOLL_CTL_DEL) here where you print out its error. If the error comes from the code you have shown, it is because you have  close(epollfd)` , or because you have some undefined behavior e.g. overwriting the epollfd variable

Comment: @nos Thanks. Finally I found that there exist data race + overflow in another thread which overwrites epoll_fd to an invalid value here.

Comment: Something to note about EPOLL https://idea.popcount.org/2017-03-20-epoll-is-fundamentally-broken-22/